# Remove custom dialog color outside the rounded corner in android

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-drawable

I'm trying to apply rounded corners to my custom dialog. Dialog shows the rounded corners correctly but the outer space of corner is turned into white.

**drawable/dialog_message_background**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="?postCardBackground"/> //light black color
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**My layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    android:background="@drawable/dialog_message_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_message_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogMessageTv"
                android:text="Error occured"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="?attr/postUserNameColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/messageDialogImg"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/messageDialogOkBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_purple_btn_back"
            android:text="ok"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output window**

[image: Output screen showing white corners outside dialog]

Help me to remove the white color outside the custom dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shape to achieve a `Dialog` with rounded corners.
You can override the `getTheme()` method in your `DialogFragment`:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class RoundedDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedCornersDialog

    //....

}
```

with:

```
<style name="RoundedCornersDialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">16dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

In Java just use

```
public class RoundedDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return   R.style.RoundedCornersDialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. can you please modify the code with Java code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in Java
just make style for the dialog

```
<style name="RoundedCornersDialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

and then assign it to the dialog

```
dialog = new Dialog(mContext,R.style.RoundedCornersDialog);
```